# In Transit Encryption

Tags: firebase, encryption

I'm currently developing an application for a client and their requirement is that the application needs in transit and at rest encryption. I assured that it was and was required to provide documentation for that. I referenced [this](https://cloud.google.com/docs/security/encryption-in-transit) documentation from Google Cloud's website. They replied by asking if my claim stands in light of the following section

> **Using a connection directly to a VM using an external IP or network load balancer IP**

> If you are connecting via the VM's external IP, or via a network-load-balanced IP, the connection does not go through the GFE. This connection is not encrypted by default and its security is provided at the user's discretion

My mobile application uses Firebase SDK to talk to the Firebase database and Firebase functions. I have no background in networking nor do I understand what is exactly being referenced here despite Googling the concepts. Is my data still encrypted? Does the above section apply to my use case?

Answer (score 0):

No, that applies only to VMs and network load balancers. Both Cloud Functions (so long as you're using `https` for all requests) and the Firebase Realtime database encrypt data in transit.